# R markdown beamer presentation: adjust the width/aspect ratio of slides

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

How to adjust the width of the slides of an R markdown presentation rendered as output format `beamer` to generate a LaTex/PDF file?
To be able to quickly adjust to a given presentation device (widescreen, 4:3 screen, ...), the aspect ratio could ideally be altered easily to take different values.

### MWE:

```
---
title: "Adjust the width/aspect ratio of slides"
output:
  # beamer_presentation: default
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
---


## Some Slides

some content
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the `aspectratio` as class option. Have a look at the beamer user guide to check the available ratios.

```
---
title: "Adjust the width/aspect ratio of slides"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "default"
    keep_tex: true
classoption: aspectratio=169    
---

## Some Slides

some content
```